# Is Sasuke's new dojutsu same as Kaguya's third eye?

Tags: naruto

**SPOILERS AHEAD**

> After Hagoromo Otsutsuki gives his Yin chakra to Sasuke, Sasuke develops a new dojutsu in his left eye.
>  
> [image]

> Is this dojutsu the same one as Kaguya and Madara's third eye?
>  
> [image]

In both cases, the eyes have circles and tomoes in them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, Sasuke's dojutsu is different from Kaguya and Madara's third eye.

Sasuke has the [**Rinnegan**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan) while Kaguya and Madara have the [**Rinne Sharingan**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinne_Sharingan).

Both the dojutsu might look similar in design, but they're not.

[image]

A side-by-side comparison of the two dojutsu shows that although they have similar circles, the Rinne-Sharingan has nine tomoe whereas Sasuke's Rinnegan has 6 tomoe.

Another visual difference between the two is the color. Later in the manga, their colors were revealed.

[image]  - Madara and Kaguya's Rinne Sharingan is **red** in color.

[image]  - Sasuke's Rinnegan is **purple** in color, just like a [normal Rinnegan](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140621040659/naruto/images/thumb/7/7e/Rinnegan.svg/300px-Rinnegan.svg.png).

Coming to technical terms, the Rinne-Sharingan can be acquired only if the person is the Ten-Tail's jinchuriki. Also, it is seen that the Rinne-Sharingan is activated on the user's forehead as a new eye, unlike how the Rinnegan is attained.

Therefore, it is clear that both the dojutsu are not the same and what Sasuke has is a Rinnegan.

Comment: It might be interesting to compare them both against the 10tails' eyes

Comment: @Vogel612 the Ten Tails has the Rinne Sharingan on its head.